# How to convert a string of numbers to an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a pretty big JavaScript array with integers between -10 and 10. I want to save those in a database, so I have to send them to PHP using the jQuery $.post function; however, the array is too big, so I converted the array to a string in JavaScript. 
I want to convert it back to an array of integers in PHP. How can I do this?

This is my code, so far:

```
function updateDb(){
for(i = 0; i < inputSquares.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
        perceptronsWeights[10*i+j] = inputSquares[i].weights[j]
    };
};

var pws = String(perceptronsWeights);
alert(typeof pws);

$.post("updateDatabase.php", {size: size, weights:pws}).done (
    function(data) {
        alert (data);
    }
)
```

And, in my PHP file, I use:

```
$weightsString = $_POST['weights'];
$pws = array_map("intval", explode(",", $weightsArray));
echo $pws;
```

I have also tried `explode()` without `array_map` and `str_split`, but both of them give me this error:

> Notice:  Array to string conversion in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ANN_JS\updateDatabase.php on line 19
>   Array

Line 19 is `echo $pws;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `print_r` or `var_dump` for echoing the array details for $pws.
 If you want through `echo` then try

```
`echo implode(" ",$pws);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r($pws)` to print `array`